# Why does it says TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting?

Tags: python, typeerror

When I did this input

```
def enter_file():
        global file
        file = open(r"c:\words.txt", "w")
        file.write("dog bee bear cat")
        file.close()
        global file_path
        file_path = input("please enter a file path: ")
        global index
        index = input("please enter an index: ")

def choose_word(file_path, index):
        file = open(file_path, "r")
        words_list = file.read().split(" ")
        no_doubles = list(dict.fromkeys(words_list))
        tuple_out = []
        tuple_out.append(len(no_doubles))
        tuple_out.append(words_list[index % len(words_list) - 1]) 
        global secret_word
        secret_word = tuple_out[1]   
        print("_ " * len(secret_word)) 

def main():
        print(enter_file())
        print(choose_word(file_path, index))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I got a type error traceback that said:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting at line 17
What is the problem why and how to fix it

Comment: `index` is a *string*, so `%` is [printf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) **not** modulo. See the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449427/3001761. Also note that you don't need to subtract 1 from the length to wrap the index around the end of the list, unless you're actually trying to miss the last value.

Comment: It looks like `index` should be an `int`, not a `string`. By the way, using global variables in this manner is very bad practice. You should be taking advantage of return values, arguments, and OOP.

Comment: @iz_ beat me to it! Your program really needs some refactoring. Also, always share the entire error message, and use a context manager to handle that file object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to convert your index input into an int variable so that you can make sure you are selecting an integer index from your list of words.

```
def enter_file():
        global file
        file = open(r"c:\words.txt", "w")
        file.write("dog bee bear cat")
        file.close()
        global file_path
        file_path = input("please enter a file path: ")
        global index
        index = input("please enter an index: ")

def choose_word(file_path, index):
        file = open(file_path, "r")
        words_list = file.read().split(" ")
        no_doubles = list(dict.fromkeys(words_list))
        tuple_out = []
        tuple_out.append(len(no_doubles))
        tuple_out.append(words_list[int(index) % len(words_list) - 1]) 
        global secret_word
        secret_word = tuple_out[1]   
        print("_ " * len(secret_word)) 

def main():
        print(enter_file())
        print(choose_word(file_path, index))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```